# I can't create the repository datalab-notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-platform

Try to create a datalab session following this page:
https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts

```
$datalab create instance-name
```

after running this code, a error occured.

> ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.create) ResponseError: status=[PERMISSION_DENIED], code=[403], message=[You do not have permission to access project [project-name] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission].
>   Failed to find or create the repository datalab-notebooks.
>   Ask a project owner to create it for you.

I am the editor role in this project.

I think editor has permission to access project...

Why does this error occur?

And how can I create datalab-notebook?

Please any idea for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITOR permissions are not sufficient to create a repository; you have to have the OWNER role to do that.

You have two options for this:

1. Ask a project owner to create the repository

or

2. Pass in the `--no-create-repository` flag to tell the `datalab` command to skip repository creation.

Comment: Thank you!!
I tried your second solution and could open datalab!!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the `Cloud Source Repositories` API.

The easiest way to do this is to click on the link that can sometimes be within the error message you receive - like below but with your own account specifics and your project name at the end: `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/sourcerepo.googleapis.com/?project=<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME>`

and may be hidden within the error message you received much like this:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.create) ResponseError: status=[PERMISSION_DENIED],
code=[403], message=[User[<YOURACCOUNT@gmail.com>] does not have permission to access 
project[<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME>] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission].
details:
- Cloud Source Repositories API is not enabled. Please enable the API on the Google
  Cloud console. 
  enable at: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/sourcerepo.googleapis.com/?project=<YOUR-PROJECT-NAME>
Failed to find or create the repository datalab-notebooks.
Ask a project owner to create it for you.
```

Hover over the address listed in the error message in your google cloud shell and you will even get a hyperlink to take you right there. Enable it when the page finishes opening.

Alternatively, you can track the API down by going to `APIs & Services/Library` and searching for `Cloud Source Repositories`. Click on the card that comes up, and then when the destination page finishes loading, click the `ENABLE` button.

You should be able to run the
`datalab create instance-name`
command in your google cloud shell now without issue.